# FFmpeg grabbing RTSP IP Camera

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264, rtsp

Trying to correctly grab via FFmpeg an IP camera, Hikvision brand.

That is what going on with FFmpeg:

```
        "ffmpeg",
        "-rtsp_transport", "tcp",
        "-stimeout", "3000000",
        "-re",
        "-i", stream,
        "-vcodec", "copy",
        "-acodec", "libfdk_aac",
        "-f", "segment",
        "-segment_list_type", "m3u8",
        "-segment_list", name,
        "-segment_list_size", "1",
        "-segment_format", "mpegts",
        "-segment_time", "5",
         segment_filename,
```

The result is always with these warning:

[segment @ 0x560d0df9d1e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 33976, current: 7200; changing to 33977. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.

I am stuck with these warnings, don't know how to get them away without re-encoding the stream. Indeed that is spoiling my timestamps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that your camera doesn't implement RTCP (sender report correctly).

RTP is about the media streams.
RTSP is the control protocol setting up the connection.
RTCP is the sender report.

RTCP generates the correct timestamp from the wall clock and the RTP timestamps.
More than once I have seen incorrect of missing RTCP implementation.

Use Wireshark to verify that your camera gives you correct timestamp or run Live555 in a debugger.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes you are right. Hik camera does not send rtcp sender request. Though I've searched ffmpeg docs and there is an option like using wall clock for the stream. Maybe I am not applying it the right way, but gives me no result for better timestamps

Comment: Without sender report you won't get good time stamps. The RTP time stamps must have random start value and may overflow and roll. You can't make up the correct time stamp if you don't get them through the sender report.

Comment: @MarkusSchumann So there is no solution for these Hikvision cameras then? I am facing the same issue

Comment: @astralmaster - you could contact the manufacture or do some sort of poor man's sync: ignore the bogus timestamps and re-stamp your samples with the arrival time. This is not an option if you really care about A/V sync.